# Loading jQuery as soon as the HTML is loaded (not other Javascript nor CSS)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want an arrow to show as soon as the HTML is loaded (without waiting for the other JavaScript of plugins to load. So I tried this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function PreLoad() {
    $('.page-template-front-page-2-php #header .container').append('<div id="top-line-arrow-home"></div>');
    $('.post-type-archive-games #menu-item-402').append('<div id="top-line-arrow"></div>');
    $('.post-type-archive-news #menu-item-420').append('<div id="top-line-arrow"></div>');
    $('.post-type-archive-jobs #menu-item-412').append('<div id="top-line-arrow"></div>');
    $('.page-template-about-page-php #menu-item-19').append('<div id="top-line-arrow"></div>');
    $('.page-template-contact-page-php #menu-item-22').append('<div id="top-line-arrow"></div>');
  }
</script>

<body <?php body_class(); ?> onload="javascript:PreLoad();">
```

But the arrow is still appearing after all the other JavaScript (in the header) load.

Is there any other way of approaching this?

Comment: If you're using WordPress you should load scripts the proper way, with `wp_enqueue_script` where you can define dependencies and order and also if you want to load in the head or the footer. Same with the styles and `wp_enqueue_style`.

Comment: Maybe have a look [Here](http://headjs.com/)

Answer (score 0):

there are several alternatives to this, it might be possible that your function `PreLoad()` is taking some time to execute which let other js code to execute earlier because there is no condition i believe which is blocking other code from being execute after your function has finished its execution.

putting other javascript code in body section and `PreLoad()` in head section will not help as much either.

one alternative you can try is put your `PreLoad()` in document ready event as normal, and shift your other javascript code in `$(window).load()`. because `$(window).load()` executes a fraction of time later then document ready event.

Another way of doing this is by using [$.deffered.](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/)

```
var FirstFunction = function () {
 // creating a deferred object
var obj = $.Deferred();

 // do something with your code

setTimeout(function () {
 //call `resolve` on the deferred object once you're done!
 obj .resolve();
}, 3000);

 // return the deferred object
 return obj;
};

 // define SecondFunction here
var SecondFunction = function () {
 console.log('This is another function');
};

/* call FirstFunction and use the `done()` method
with `SecondFunction ` as it's parameter */

FirstFunction().done(SecondFunction);
```

hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

use external .js file and refer to it and the jquery in the head befor the css lik to make sure it load first

```
<head>
  <title>
  </title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jQuery-v2.js"></script>    
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/external.js"></script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style1.css" />
</head>
```

Comment: this is a bad idea in my book, what if you are trying to add a class on DOM element dynamically or overrriding styles in your js code, you might get unexpected results.

Comment: i know that yet he want to load it even before css so he may add any other statements like you mentioned in another .js file and link it appropriately before the ending body tag